# how to add to embedded binaries in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I'm under Project --> General --> Embedded Binaries.

I clicked the "+" button below and then tried to add a library. But it doesn't appear there (like it does when I add to "Linked frameworks and Libraries" right underneath it.)

Is there  reason for this? Or is there something else I have to do?

Comment: Do you have a binary in your project?

Comment: at the risk of sounding stupid, I'm not exactly sure. So far I have done this: Start new Xcode project, and then installed SwiftBond through cocoa pods. Does importing a third party framework such as Swiftbond count as having imported a binary?

The Bond.framework is linked in the "Linked frameworks and Binaries" section just underneath.

Comment: You don't have an embedded binary you need to import.  CocoaPods import source code and compile with your project (it's a linked framework).  You will have to `#import` it in the appropriate source files.